# Obsession over mathematical constants

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word for "obsession over mathematical constants" (like pi, golden ratio etc)?

I want to use it like this:

> He was obsessed with the golden ratio.  This [term for obsession] was the outcome of ....

Comment: I want to call it phyphillia or the more extreme phymania as Phy (φ) is the greek letter used to express the golden ratio specifically.

Comment: We don't even have a single word for "mathematical constants", let alone a word for the state of being obsessed by them.

Comment: Arithmomania is probably as close as you'll get: obsession with numbers / counting everything.

Comment: However you look at it, it's irrational.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that was one of hits I got in Google Search. But I think it will convey very negative aspect of it and also it is different than specific constants. Maybe that is more general form of all theses sub-obsessions.

Comment: ***fixation*** fits your blank.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs.: Do you have any examples of _phi_ having a combining form _phy-_ ? Very unlikely, I would think.

Comment: No, not at all and I agree. That's why it's a comment not an answe.

Comment: There's no need for a single word when two or more will do just fine in order to say exactly what you mean, 'obsession with numbers' or 'obsession with arcane mathematical constants'. If you must coin a fancy sounding term... ugh, just don't. rewirte your sentence to make it flow better rather than looking for a fancy term.

Comment: With respect to *arithmomania*: *"I think it will convey very negative aspect of it."* *Obsession* mostly ***is*** considered negative in a context like this—and *mania* is a common synonym. If you don't want something that has negative connotations, then don't ask for something that involves *obsession*. I'd like to say *arithmoPHILIA*. It's not a defined word, but that's doesn't mean it's not grammatical.